# GetAccessTokenAsync silently fails, unable to catch issue in debugger

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to get a `GraphServiceClient` so I can integrate with Teams.

When I try to get a token so I can autenticate with AAD, the line

`accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvide.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/");`

Fails silently and the application exits, I'm not able to catch any exception or see the issue.

```
private async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphApiClient()
{
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    string accessToken = "";
    try 
    {
        accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider
            .GetAccessTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/");
    } catch(AggregateException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }


    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage
        .Headers
        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }));

    return graphServiceClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, forgot to await the method:

`GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GetGraphApiClient();`